# Why does JavaScript string.split(/[ -_]+/) act as if quotes (' and ") are included in the [group]?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

When using `/[ -_]+/` as parameter to string.split in JavaScript, it acts as if it was `/['\"]+/`

```
"a'b".split(/[ -_]+/)
'a"b'.split(/[ -_]+/)
```

returns

```
["a", "b"]
```

I only see this behavior with the exact regex: `[ -_]` i.e. space, hyphen, and underscore. If I remove any of these 3 characters it behaves (what appears to me to be) correctly, by not splitting on ' and "

Is this behavior correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`-` has special meaning inside of character classes.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) It denotes a range of characters. In this case the range is from space (ASCII 32) to underscore (ASCII 95). Because the ASCII codes for `'` and `"` are 39 and 34 (respectively) they fall within that range.

Escape it if you want to split on a literal `-`;

```
"a'b".split(/[ \-_]+/)
```

Or make the hyphen the first character of the character class:

```
"a'b".split(/[- _]+/)
```

Comment: who answers a newbies question gets the credit snd doesn't have the pay it forward to up the person's question? Build up your community don't just take from it

Comment: @JustinMeskan IMHO, answering a question contributes to building up the community. Do you disagree?

Answer (score 3):

The hyphen here is being used to specify a range of characters.

`[ -_]` means "*every character between space and underscore*."

So... The single and double quote characters clearly come between the space and underscore characters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `regex` is wrong, the "-*" that means:* - a single character in the range between   and _.

You can test your regexp in http://regex101.com/#javascript site.